# Pytest Parametrization using a dynamic list

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a pytest, which takes in two inputs below@

- datadictionary_from_excel - is read from CVS
- customer = ["C1", "C2",.., Cn] - this list is not fixed and is generated at run time, so
  there can be any number of customers

I have the below function, which takes the data that is read from the CSV, and performs actions based on the customer id passed. The number of customers here is unknown. How could I handle this in pytest?

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_dict, customer", [(input_dict, customer)])
def test_input_values(datadictionary_from_excel, customer_id):
    perform some action based on customer_id which keeps changing and the input_dict which is constant
    assert above action is succesfull
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe get your data loaded before any tests are run by creating a file called `conftest.py` at the root of your tests directory. When pytests see such a file, it will run it before the tests, so its a good time to load up data needed by all tests. And you can create them as fixtures.

Comment: @Andrew Allaire - Loading the data is not a problem, but since we don't know the number of customers, how to parametrize that list of customers is the tricky thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that reads from the csv file and creates the customers list, and than pass the values to the test using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`

```
def data_source():
    input_dict = read_from_csv()
    customers = get_customers() # ["C1", "C2",.., Cn]
    for customer in customers:
        yield input_dict, customer


@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_dict, customer", data_source())
def test_input_values(input_dict, customer):
    # input_dict is the all data from the csv
    # customer is one item from the customers list, C2 for example
```